# 404 Error - Jenkins not running but Tomcat is

Tags: jenkins, http-status-code-404, tomcat8

I am new in this area. I see that the Tomcat service is running.

I verified that by entering URL `http://localhost:8080`.

[image: Tomcat running here]

But when I type `http://localhost:8080/jenkins` I get a 404 error.

[image: 404 Error]

I have verified the availability of `<TOMCAT_HOME>/webapps/jenkins.war`.

[image: Jenkins.war is available]

Does this mean I have to re-install **both Tomcat and Jenkins**? Or is there something more that I need to do?

**UPDATED:**

I downloaded jenkins.war version 1.658 from here - https://updates.jenkins-ci.org/download/war/ and replaced the old jenkins.war (version 1.568) with the relatively new one (version 1.658). I got the Error message with stacktrace when I tried `http://localhost:8080/jenkins` -

```
AWT is not properly configured on this server. Perhaps you need to run your container with "-Djava.awt.headless=true"? See also: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+got+java.awt.headless+problem
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no freetype in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at sun.font.FontManagerNativeLibrary$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.font.FontManagerNativeLibrary.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.font.SunFontManager$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.font.SunFontManager.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at sun.font.FontManagerFactory$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.font.FontManagerFactory.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Font.getFont2D(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Font.getFamily(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Font.getFamily_NoClientCode(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Font.getFamily(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Font.toString(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.util.ChartUtil.<clinit>(ChartUtil.java:255)
    at hudson.WebAppMain.contextInitialized(WebAppMain.java:186)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4760)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5184)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:724)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:700)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:714)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:919)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1704)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: jenkins should run Independent of tomcat and should have different port number. its best to run jenkins as a service in windows. How did u install jenkins in wondows? can u share the steps briefly

Comment: This was already installed when I saw.. I'm not sure what steps were executed to install.. Also, there is no windows service for jenkins as such.

Comment: try to install jenkins. follow this link bellow https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins+as+a+Windows+service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a discrepency in the jdk that was installed.

**More information:** if you are upgrading jdk version, you would have to wipe clean the older versions of jdk and uninstall Jenkins. If you are running Jenkins through Tomcat, that too will have to be uninstalled and everything will have to be re-installed.